# Handle ElasticSearch errors to be redirected to BigQuery table/errortopic for logging using Dataflow/Beam in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Handle ElasticSearch errors to be written to BigQuery table/errortopic using Dataflow / apache beam framework/GCP.
We are looking to capture the errors in elasticSearch so that we don't miss any data .
Specifically for types of errors in elasticSearch and how to redirect it to bigquery for logging all errors.

Exception can be recoverable/non-recoverable type.
eg-ConnectTimeOut,Keystore load error etc

These errors needs to be logged in bigquery and also published to error topic.

I tried to find the answer but I wasn't able to find anything around this topic.

Below Code snippet where we initialize and write to our elasticsearch -
This custom template we created is to read from pubsub and write to ES.

/*
* Step #1: Read from a PubSub subscription.
*/

PCollection messages = null;

```
if (options.getUseSubscription()) {

  messages =

          pipeline.apply(

                  "ReadPubSubSubscription",

                  PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes()
                          .fromSubscription(options.getInputSubscription()));

}
```

/*
* Step #2: Transform the PubsubMessages into Json documents.
*/

PCollectionTuple convertedPubsubMessages = messages.apply(

```
      "ConvertMessageToJsonDocument",new PubSubMessageToJsonDocument(options));
```

/*

- Step #3a: Write Json documents into Elasticsearch using {@link ElasticsearchTransforms.WriteToElasticsearch}.
  */

convertedPubsubMessages

```
      .get(TRANSFORM_OUT)

      .apply(
              "GetJsonDocuments",
              MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings()).via(FailsafeElement::getPayload)
```

)
.apply(

```
              "WriteToElasticsearch",

              ElasticsearchTransforms.WriteToElasticsearch.newBuilder()
                      .setOptions(options.as(WriteToElasticsearchOptions.class))

                      .build());
```

Comment: Quick Question: Are you running this pipeline/template in GCP's dataflow? Also if I got the question correct you wish to log the errors generated from this pipeline to a Bigquery table and a pub sub topic.

Comment: Yes it's running in gcp data flow , yes that's understanding is correct. We want no loss of message i.e successful+failure=total messages, error msgs to be logged in big query and error topic

Comment: We also have a similar use-case wherein we route all the logs generated from the logger, worker logs, system logs to a BigQuery table.  We use log Exporter where you can filter the logs produced from all the different GCP services based on logging level, service type etc. Then route those logs to a sink both BigQuery table and PubSub topics are supported. You can refer more on this article here -> https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2 . Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks but i have one doubt we want to log not only the error message description but also want to log the originalPayload, header attributes which contains msgId and other metadata and we should also have control to categorize error message as recoverable or non-recoverable so that we know which messages can be reprocessed .Also i believe the logs written by logExporter to bigquery should adhere to particular schema.
Note- we are not logging payload and metadata in worker logs due to security reason. 
Can log Exporter help us in achieving above if yes example of it would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not really sure how you would handle such a use case, we don't have a requirement to log the payload within the pipeline. I guess you can try to expand the WriteToElasticsearch somehow to log the payload along with the error message in a catch block so that the Log Exporter can pick that up. For the schema of the log exporter table, mostly a view is built on top of it based on the business requirements.

Comment: Some Payloads are sensitive so we can't log all payloads , however more logging means more cost involved. looks like we need to integrate ElasticSearch with Bigquery so that we can log the errors in BigQuery in  a controlled way.

Comment: I have bookmarked this question, if you're able to find a solution please add it here as well.